# background-attachment: fixed does not work correctly with background-position

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a background-attachment: fixed. I want to align it using background-position: center bottom; if you change bottom to top, there are changes, but not perfect. That is, the background shifts, but only slightly, and not to the top or bottom. For example, when using bottom, the background moves slightly down from the center, but not to the bottom of the image. How can I move the background to the bottom of the image?

```css
#myblock {
  background-image: url("https://masyamba.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82/36-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA.jpg");
  background-position-y: bottom;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header id="myblock">
  <div id="textinf">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. What do you think "bottom" means bottom **of**?

Comment: you need to share your *full* code because fixed consider the viewport and not the div element.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you run the code on stackoverflow, you will see that the cat's paws are visible in the background, although if you open the original image, you will not see the paws at the bottom, but only the jeans

Comment: as I said, fixed consider the viewport and the element. (run the code full screen and you will get a different result)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interesting result. Then the question changes a little. How do I make sure that regardless of the screen, there is still an image size?

Comment: @Quentin Maybe you know?